# What is actually happening when I add a dependency in Spring (using Maven)?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am trying to figure out how to use the Spring framework from scratch over the summer. I am very new to Spring, and even newer to Maven, although I am somewhat familiar with Java and using Eclipse.

While working through a few Spring tutorials online (such as [this one](http://www.java-school.net/spring/di) – the site is in Korean, but the code is in Java), I came across the term **dependency injection** many times. From what I've learned so far, and please correct me if I misunderstand, adding (injecting) a dependency is done through adding some code into the pom.xml file, such as:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

But what exactly is this doing? What are `groupId`, `artifactId`, and `version`, and how are they used? How does this tie in with the bigger Spring picture? I get the basics of accessing databases using SQL, but I am struggling to figure out how to transition from JDBC to Spring, and it's especially hard trudging through unfamiliar tools (like Spring and Maven) by myself.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you're showing is from a `pom.xml` file - this is a descriptor file that allows **Maven** to build your project. Maven has no relation with Spring - you can use maven completely without Spring. And Spring can be used without Maven. You need to read tutorials for both Maven and Spring.

Comment: Hi, please have a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) because you're going to get things like http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I see... Thank you. That actually clarifies quite a lot.

Comment: @D.B. Thank you, I'll keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up two concepts here. The dependencies declared in Maven have nothing to do with Spring's dependency injection.

Declaring a dependency in Maven just makes this module available to the build. It adds it to the classpath.

Dependency injection on the other hand injects beans (or other data) that a another bean needs via the constructor or via setters.